# Aspnetcore.Identity.EntityFramework 6.0.9 , SignInManager doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.9 Nuget package and I can't use SignInManager method.
Has this method been replaced by another method or am I making a mistake at some point?

I Added this code in Program cs

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

[image: Here My Code]

SignInManager asks me to install AspNetCore.Identity while UserManager works with nuget package I installed

Comment: I think you'll be missing `AddDefaultTokenProviders` ([see also](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Data/Extensions/MintPlayerExtensions.cs#L37))

Comment: I don't use it as a JWT, but I still tried, no results